# find closest div of last div - with other div mixed up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have something like this:

```
<div class="sidebar">
<script></script>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<script></script>
<div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

divs a and b can have any class.
i know how to get any of the divs by class, but the classes can be differents.

i what to find the closest previous div of the last div.c

```
$("div.c").prev() = gives me <script>;
$("div.c").prev('div') = gives me {nothing};
$("div.c").closest() = gives me the same div;
```

remember i dont know the specific classes.
thanks for the help!

Comment: `$("div.c").prev('div')` would only work if the immediate prior sibling was a div which it is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use [`.prevAll(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) at this context,

```
$("div.c").prevAll('div:first')
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/76tuaour/)

See, Basically `.prev()` is equals to `.previousElementSibling`, It will select the immediate previous element sibling(not textNode/commentNode etc..) to the source element based on the selector. It will not skip the elements to grab the target element as per the supplied selector.

Comment: +1 Or `$("div.c").prevAll('div').first()` or `$("div.c").prevAll('div').eq(0)`  Note that `prevAll` returns elements in selection order NOT DOM order. i.e.  the elements are returned in order beginning with the closest sibling.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `prev().prev()`:

```
$('div.c').prev().prev().css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

I find this to be a quite *natural* solution... :-)

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tp59y3xx/)